# javascript + postgres: timezone and timestamp usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

I'm not quite understanding the timestamp usage,
e.g.
User create article and they can choose `PublishDate` , the system also store `CreateDate` automatically.

a. Should I make `PublishDate` and `CreateDate` timestamp with time zone and set utc?

b. User post string and then I convert like below use `momentjs` to utc timestamp and store,  when someone select this row , show them as user client time reverse use `momentjs`

c. I use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to the `CreateDate`, the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` does that mean the server time?  am I doing correct?

My thinking is I always insert utc timezone timestamp to the database, and wherever the place user/client read, convert the data to user/client timezone? am I doing correct?

a.  my database(postgres) created by

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Article"(
"ArticleId" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"PublishDate" timestamp with time zone,
"Active" bit NOT NULL,
"CreateByUserId" integer,
"CreateDate" timestamp with time zone,
PRIMARY KEY ("ArticleId")
);

SET timezone = 'UTC';
```

b. user submit post to store (nodejs)

```
// publishDate: '{"y":2015,"m":8,"d":16,"h":15,"mi":46,"s":24}
var publishDate = JSON.parse(req.body.publishDate); 

var leadingZeroAndDateFormat = function(publishDate) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    if (publishDate.m < 10) { publishDate.m = '0'+publishDate.m; }
    if (publishDate.d < 10) { publishDate.d = '0'+publishDate.d; }
    if (publishDate.h < 10) { publishDate.h = '0'+publishDate.h; }
    if (publishDate.mi < 10) { publishDate.mi = '0'+publishDate.mi; }
    if (publishDate.s < 10) { publishDate.s = '0'+publishDate.s; }
    var str = publishDate.y+'-'+publishDate.m+'-'+publishDate.d+' '+publishDate.h+':'+publishDate.mi+':'+publishDate.s;
    var utc = moment(str).unix();
    fulfill(utc);
  });
};
```

c. insert to database the `CreateDate` use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
var insertArticle = function(publishDate, active, createByUserId) {
return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
  var query = 'INSERT INTO "Article" ("PublishDate","Active","CreateByUserId","CreateDate") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) RETURNING "ArticleId"';
  dbClient.query(query,[publishDate,active,createByUserId], function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      fulfill(result);
    }
  });
});
};
```

**Update**
When I change all column without timezone then I execute `insertArticle` shows the error

`{ [error: date/time field value out of range: "1439717298"]
  name: 'error',
  length: 158,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '22008',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: 'Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.',
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'datetime.c',
  line: '3775',
  routine: 'DateTimeParseError' }`

```
var insertArticle = function(publishDate, active, createByUserId) {
return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
  var query = 'INSERT INTO "Article" ("PublishDate","Active","CreateByUserId","CreateDate") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "ArticleId"';
  dbClient.query(query,[publishDate,active,createByUserId,moment.utc().unix()], function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
       fulfill(result);
    }
  });
});
};
```

Comment: Use always UTC times and time stamp without time zone, since there is no need to store different time zones. Then in the presentation layer handle the zones if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for reply, does that mean make the column set without timezone?   then when insert use momentjs utc timestamp

Comment: Yes, make the column in the database without time zone and always store UTC times from moment. This way you always know what the data is and can handle it easily. Presentation can be done in any time zone you choose easily also.

Comment: A) Always use type timestamptz. B) Always insert as UTC, which is the format that PostgreSQL understands automatically always. If you use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), you get UTC always by default.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest way is to always store time stamps without time zone and in UTC. This way it is always easy to use them for display and calculations. A difference is just a subtraction and comparisons go directly.

If the column was a time stamp with time zone, then the input would be converted to UTC anyway, but the output would be in the currently set time zone and if it's not set properly it might show wrong values. It also makes the database less efficient.

In the presentation layer the timestamps can be shown in the proper time zone and values input can also be converted to UTC for storage.

This is the simplest, most efficient and most flexible way of handling timestamps.

Using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will get the timestamp from the server at the time of execution.

Comment: I update the column to without time zone,  but when I execute ` insertArticle` shows the error `[error: date/time field value out of range: "1439715951000"] `

Comment: That seems to be a millisecond value, probably UNIX epoch? Then you need to insert `timestamp '1970-1-1' + interval '12357 seconds'` to achieve an actual timestamp. Of course the number converted to seconds.

Comment: insert ` timestamp '1970-1-1' + interval '12357 seconds'`  ? you mean execute this on database sql

Comment: Yes, instead of just sending the number, send that with the number of seconds if moment gives it out as such. I'm not familiar with moment/node.js so unfortunately can't give the best answer. I would think there was a way to bind a timestamp/datetime value directly also.

Comment: that's work if sometimes my server is in europe or usa ? i'd like to have a right date, and dont' depends of server location

Answer (score 10):

The incoming timestamps without timezone are parsed in local time instead of UTC -- I'd call this a bug in node-postgres. Anyway, you can override it to do the right thing by adding the following code:

```
pg.types.setTypeParser(1114, function(stringValue) {
    console.log(stringValue);
    return new Date(Date.parse(stringValue + "+0000"));
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I saw this piece of code in seqlize.js docs too. But where i should write this function? get confused!

Comment: just add it to the top of your node.js source file -- before you make pg.connect calls

Comment: Just a note for others, i wanted to achieve the same thing, but my date / time column was of type `TIMESTAMP`.  Using the above code with a value of `1184` instead worked

Comment: Using the node-postgres module version 8.11.2, I have observed that `pg.types.builtins.TIMESTAMPTZ` has a value of `1184`, and `pg.types.builtins.TIMESTAMP` has a value of `1114`.  I got the idea to use `pg.types.builtins` constants from https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types.

Comment: Overriding the type parser for TIMESTAMP, and appending "+0000" to the given value, as @DannyDulai answered, worked for me.   Thanks.